# JupyterLab in Google Cloud Platform won't connect to Google Drive

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, jupyter-lab

I've looked at a [Medium guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/integrate-jupyterlab-with-google-drive-98d13e340c63) on connecting JupyterLab to Google Drive. After having followed the steps in this guide, I'm still unable to connect.

> Google API Error
> Not a valid origin for the client: https://3xxxx-dot-us-west1.notebooks.googleusercontent.com has not been whitelisted for client ID xyz-123.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID.

I believe I have already done this. I've tried troubleshooting and having a buddy look but the error persists when I add in the clientid per the instructions.

Is it possible that JupyterLab hosted on my virtual machine on GCP is not able to connect? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried to run it locally on your PC first?

Comment: It works fine on my local. The same steps on my vm fail. Is it possible to whitelist the client? I can't do the same thing I did for my local (add my email to the OAuth consent screen)...it fails when I try.

Comment: Have you tried whitelisting the URL that they give you? You can do so under Authorized JavaScript origins (the guide only makes you add `http://localhost:8888`)

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. No luck. It won't let me whitelist that specific URL.